# Correct data not showing up and getting updated in checkboxes when records selected

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

I am trying to use the 'Update' statement from SQL in my java program. Additionally, I've used the `JTable.getSelectedRow()` method to load the data stored in a certain record into my checkboxes.

The fields 'English', 'Bangla', 'Burmese', 'Communicative', 'Basic Computing' and 'Experience' are boolean values set by clicking the check box. However, whenever I run the update query after altering the existing values, my `JTable` doesn't show the freshly updates ones. Additionally, the program doesn't load the correct data into the fields and boxes if I update a record and then click on it.

**I've tried** creating a new JTable and have re-written the 'Update' JButton function again. I've checked the indices of the specified checkboxes but still, whenever I click on a record after it has been supposedly 'updated', the altered checkboxes don't get selected/ deselected.
[Check Box not same as JTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbOBm.png)

```java
    public ArrayList<User> userList()
       {
           ArrayList<User> usersList = new ArrayList<>();
           try {
               Class.forName(driver);
               Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
               String query1 = "SELECT * FROM CANDIDATEINFORMATION";
               PreparedStatement prepStat = con.prepareStatement(query1);
               ResultSet rs = prepStat.executeQuery();
               User user;

               while(rs.next()){
                   user = new User(rs.getInt(
                   "Candidate_ID"), rs.getString("candidate_Name"), rs.getString("candidate_Surname"), rs.getString("Nationality"), rs.getBoolean("english"), rs.getBoolean("bangla"), rs.getBoolean("burmese"),
                   rs.getBoolean("communication"), rs.getBoolean("basic_computing"), rs.getBoolean("experience"));
                   usersList.add(user);
               }

           } catch (Exception e) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
           }

           return usersList;
       }

    // following method displays MySQL data into JTable
       public void Show_candidate_table(){
           ArrayList<User> list = userList();
           DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) CandidateTable.getModel();

           Object[] row = new Object[10];
           for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
           {
               row[0] = list.get(i).getID();
               row[1] = list.get(i).getCandName();
               row[2] = list.get(i).getCandSurname();
               row[3] = list.get(i).getNationality();
               row[4] = list.get(i).getCandEnglish();
               row[5] = list.get(i).getCandBangla();
               row[6] = list.get(i).getCandBurmese();
               row[7] = list.get(i).getCandCommunicative();
               row[8] = list.get(i).getCandBasicComp();
               row[9] = list.get(i).getCandExperienced();
              // row[10] = list.get(i).getDocSuf();

               model.addRow((Object[]) row);
           }    
       }

    private void CandidateTableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            
            // display selected record to text fields 
             // Get The Index Of The Selected Row 

            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) CandidateTable.getModel();
            int selectedRow = CandidateTable.getSelectedRow();

            candNameBox.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedRow, 1).toString());
            candSurnameBox.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedRow, 2).toString());

            String nationality = model.getValueAt(selectedRow, 3).toString();

            switch(nationality){
                 case "Chinese":
                     nationalityBox.setSelectedIndex(0);

                     break;
                 case "Indian":
                     nationalityBox.setSelectedIndex(1);

                     break;
                 case "Burmese":
                     nationalityBox.setSelectedIndex(2);

                     break;
                 case "Bangladeshi":
                     nationalityBox.setSelectedIndex(3);

                     break;
                 case "Singaporean":
                     nationalityBox.setSelectedIndex(4);

                     break;
                 case "Malaysian":
                     nationalityBox.setSelectedIndex(5);

                     break;

             }

             boolean english = (boolean) model.getValueAt(selectedRow, 4);
             if(english){
                 engCheckBox.setSelected(true);
             }
             boolean bangla = (boolean) model.getValueAt(selectedRow, 5);
             if(bangla){
                 bangCheckBox.setSelected(true);
             }
             boolean burmese = (boolean) model.getValueAt(selectedRow, 6);
             if(burmese){
                 burmeseCheckBox.setSelected(true);
             }
             boolean communicative = (boolean) model.getValueAt(selectedRow, 7);
             if(communicative){
                 commCheckBox.setSelected(true);
             }
             boolean bas_comp = (boolean) model.getValueAt(selectedRow, 8);
             if(bas_comp){
                 bascompCheckBox.setSelected(true);
             }
             boolean exper = (boolean) model.getValueAt(selectedRow, 9);
             if(exper){
                 experCheckBox.setSelected(true);
             }

        }              


     // the following method updates the candidate record
        private void UpdateRecordButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
            try {
                Class.forName(driver);
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

                int row = CandidateTable.getSelectedRow();
                String val2 = (CandidateTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());

                String sql = "UPDATE CANDIDATEINFORMATION SET CANDIDATE_NAME=?, CANDIDATE_SURNAME=? , NATIONALITY=? , ENGLISH=? , BURMESE=? ,BANGLA=? ,COMMUNICATION=? , BASIC_COMPUTING=?, EXPERIENCE=?  where CANDIDATE_ID=" + val2;

                PreparedStatement prepStat = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                prepStat.setString(1, candNameBox.getText());
                prepStat.setString(2, candSurnameBox.getText());

                String value = nationalityBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
                prepStat.setString(3, value);

                prepStat.setBoolean(4, engCheckBox.isSelected());
                prepStat.setBoolean(5, bangCheckBox.isSelected());
                prepStat.setBoolean(6, burmeseCheckBox.isSelected());
                prepStat.setBoolean(7, commCheckBox.isSelected());
                prepStat.setBoolean(8, bascompCheckBox.isSelected());
                prepStat.setBoolean(9, experCheckBox.isSelected());

                prepStat.executeUpdate();

                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) CandidateTable.getModel();

                model.fireTableDataChanged();
                CandidateTable.repaint();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record updated.");


            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }

        }
```

**Exception**
I got an `'ArrayOutOfBoundsException -1'` while updating and clicking on the records.

Additionally, while execution, I get the following message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
    at jobcandidatedatabse_ia.AddCandidateInfo.CandidateTableMouseClicked(AddCandidateInfo.java:529)
    at jobcandidatedatabse_ia.AddCandidateInfo.access$600(AddCandidateInfo.java:20)
    at jobcandidatedatabse_ia.AddCandidateInfo$7.mouseClicked(AddCandidateInfo.java:226)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6536)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Have you debug the code and find an exception occurs in which line no?

Comment: The message didn't specify the line number when I executed the program.

Comment: Yes, You can debug the code line by line and verify that which line is causing the issue or you may find out which method is causing an issue.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
 at jobcandidatedatabse_ia.AddCandidateInfo.CandidateTableMouseClicked(AddCandidateInfo.java:529)

Comment: It's a different exception then you have mentioned in your question.

Please update your Question with the full exception you got.

Comment: Sorry. Just made the edit.

Comment: In your program `CandidateTableMouseClicked` method you have used  `boolean exper = (boolean) ` to cast the String Value in boolean which cause the exception which you have updated on the last edit. Here I've taken `exper` as example you need to verify all the casting variables.

Comment: As specified with the question, I have to retrieve boolean values from a selected record in my JTable and highlight the checkboxes i've as selected/ unselected. Could you please suggest a solution ?

Comment: Here you can use `try catch` concept to handle type casting error. But eventually, If your first  statement `boolean english = (boolean) model.getValueAt(selectedRow, 4);` will throws error remain all will be skipped.

What is in return of this statement `model.getValueAt(selectedRow, 4);`?

Comment: The statement returns the value "true" or "false" from the specified cell of the JTable. Could you please specify how I can use a try..catch block ? Is there another way to go about it, maybe with the getColumnClass() method ?

Comment: Then debug code again and see if there is any field which returns string not true or false because your exception is all about the typecasting and I can tell you this much only based on your code I can see.

Comment: I debugged the code and fixed the String to Boolean problem. However, can you suggest any solutions for the other part of the problem: my check boxes don't mimic the same values in the JTable after an update query. I've shared an image in my post.

Comment: The database might be a distraction at this point. Create a self-contained example that returns a few hard-coded `User` entries from the `userList()` function. This may pinpoint the problem and can help others to help you.

Comment: I tried it but It seems to me that every time I try to click on the 'Update' button after altering the values in a selected record, the incorrect checkboxes get highlighted. Is there a way to correctly 'refresh' and 'update' my JTable ? (I've changed the data type from Object to Boolean in the JTable for Check boxes. Additionally, the 'button' and query now end up adding a different record altogether (surprisingly with the same ID) even when I alter JTextFields (and thus, String values).